# Search html file for random string using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use Perl to search through an html file, looking for a semi-random string and store the match in a variable or print it out.

The string is the name of a jpg image and always follows the pattern of 9 digits followed by 6 lower case letters, i.e.

```
140005917smpxgj.jpg
```

But it is random every time.  I am sure Perl can do this, but I will admit I am getting a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too complicated. You may want to watch out for varying caps in the extension, e.g. `JPG`. If that is a concern, you may add `(?i)` before the extension.

You may also wish to prevent partial names, e.g. discard a match that has more than 9 digits. That is the `(?<!\d)` part: Make sure no digit characters precede the match.

ETA: Now extracts multiple matches too, thanks to ikegami.

```
while (<>) {
    for (/(?<!\d)([0-9]{9}[a-z]{6}\.(?i)jpg)/g) {
        say;
        push @match, $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: `(?:^|\D)` can be written as `(?<!\d)`, with the advantage of being a zero-width match.

Comment: Tip: It's just as easy to look for multiple instances per line. Just change `if (/.../) { say $1; }` to `for (/.../g) { say $_; }`.

Comment: @ikegami #2: That's a good observation. I should have thought of that. #1: It cannot require a non-digit, in case a line starts with a file name. But yes, a look-behind would work too.

Comment: @ikegami Apparently, look-behind does not work with `^`, it gives the error `Variable length lookbehind not implemented`.

Comment: I presume you mean that `(?<=^|\D)` doesn't work? Yes, cause `^` is 0-length and `\D` is 1-length. That's why I used `(?<!\d)`

Comment: @ikegami `(?<!\d)` is not equivalent to `(?:^|\D)`, though, which makes me doubt look-behinds can be used in my example. I suppose one could do something like `(?<=(?<=^)|(?<=\D))`.

Comment: @TLP, For the third time, yes they are (aside from being zero-width, of course). If you disagree, give a counter example. Be sure to test it first!

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/\b\d{9}[a-z]{6}\.jpg/
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution regex is `\d{9}[a-z]{6}\.jpg`

Comment: @gpojd, You mean "escape". I applied the fix.

Answer (score 1):

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/ ( [0-9]{9} [a-z]{6} [.] jpg ) /x) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
foo 140005917smpxgj.jpg bar
sdfads 777666999abcdef.jpg dfgffgh
```

Prints:

```
140005917smpxgj.jpg
777666999abcdef.jpg
```