# Overlapping text substitution with Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file that contains a bunch of sentences. The sentences contain white space (spaces, tabs, new lines) to separate out words consisting of letter and/or digits.
I want to find the word "123" or "-123" and insert a dot (.) before the digits begin. So all occurrences of "123" and "-123" will be converted to ".123" and "-.123".

I was trying this with the following:

```
$line =~ s/(\s+-*123\s+)/getNewWord($1)/ge
```

Where $line contains a line read from the file and the function getNewWord word will put the dot(.) at appropriate place in the matched word.

But it's not working for cases where there are two consecutive "123" like " 123 123 ". As the first "123" is replaced by a " .123 " the space following the word has already been matched and the second "123" is not matched since the regex engine can't match the preceding space with that word.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see what is 'overlapping' in this question?

Comment: Probably this is a simpler solution s/(-?)\b(\d+)\b/$1.$2/g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with MRAB (and have +1'd his/her answer), but there's no real need for the `getNewWord` function. I'd change the entire statement to something like one of these:

```
$line =~ s/((?:^|\s)-?)(123)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;

$line =~ s/(?:^|(?<=\s))(-?)(123)(?=\s|$)/$1.$2/g;

$line =~ s/(?:^|(?<=\s)|(?<=\s-))(?=123(?:\s|$))/./g;
```

Comment: ruakh, thanks for the nice answer. I actually made a small mistake in the question. I want "-.123" for the input "-123", not ".-123"! Your third answer seems to do the job except this little thing. Thanks!

Comment: @GolamKawsar: Ah, that makes more sense. I've updated my answer accordingly. Sadly, the third option becomes much less graceful, because Perl only supports fixed-width look-behind, so a single look-behind can't match both `\s` and `\s-`. J.F. Sebastian's `\K`-based approach, however, is not affected by that limitation, as long as you have Perl 5.10+.

Comment: Beginning of line error. Will not match `123 foo bar`, and also only coincidentally matches end of string because of newline. If lines are chomped, you will get strange mismatches.

Comment: @TLP: Your second sentence is correct. Your first and third sentences seem debatable.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. Your second sentence seems debatable.

Comment: @TLP: Likewise. Obviously this is a symmetric relation. :-)

Comment: @ruakh Yes, it is equivalently symmetric from both our points of view. =) However, my point of view is the correct one. Since you require whitespace around your core match, `^123` (beginning) and `123$` (end) will not match, which may be a problem.

Comment: @ruakh - your second answer prints the dot before the minus sign. I think the replacement string will be $1.$2?

Comment: @GolamKawsar: You are quite right, I'll fix that. By the way, since you're still here -- can you clarify the point that TLP raises? Your original regex will not match cases where `123` or `-123` occur at the very beginning of the string or the very end of the string. I preserved that behavior in my suggested versions, but J.F. Sebastian and TLP both believe that this behavior is wrong, and that you *do* want to match those cases. If they're correct, please say so, and I'll edit my answer for that as well.

Comment: @ruakh - yes they are correct. your first answer does not match "123" that occur at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @GolamKawsar: To clarify: *none* of my versions matches "123" at the beginning of the line. This was intentional; your original regex had that property, and I thought I was supposed to preserve it. The question is not about what my answer *does*, but about what you *want* it do.

Comment: @ruakh - Yes, I just realized that none of your answer does that. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. I do need to extract "123" even if it's at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @GolamKawsar: Thanks for clarifying; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ruakh - Great! They all work now as expected. Thanks so much for taking the trouble to make them work with matches that are at the beginning and end of a line.

Comment: @ruakh Any sufficiently advanced logic is indistinguishable from divination, it seems. =P

Comment: @TLP: It's not a question of "logic", it's a question of premises. There was a mismatch between the behavior described in the question-text and the behavior of the source-code in the question. Your premise was that the text was normative, the source-code informative; my premise was the the source-code was normative (aside from the specific bug identified by the OP) and that the text was informative. Given these contrary premises, we both logically arrived at opposite conclusions. There's no need to be a jerk about it. ;-)

Comment: @ruakh I was just continuing the good-natured banter. Very impressive-sounding summation, though. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It might be slightly faster (no explicit capture) and it allows a file without leading/trailing whitespace:

```
$ echo '123 -123 -123  123' | perl -pe's/(?:^|\s+)\K(?=-?123\b)/./g'
.123 .-123 .-123  .123
```

To put `.` after `-`:

```
$ echo '123 -123 -123  123' | perl -pe's/(?:^|\s+)-*\K(?=123\b)/./g'
.123 -.123 -.123  .123
```

Comment: Note: `\K` requires Perl 5.10 or newer.

Comment: Note that word boundary assertion `\b` will match more than transition to whitespace, e.g. `123?`, `123-123` etc.

Comment: +1 for being the only one besides me to consider beginning of line.

Comment: @TLP: `\b` is by design to avoid matching `1234`. To insert `.` only leading whitespace matters.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a positive lookahead like this: `(\s+-*123)(?=\s)`.

Comment: Neither will the original regex!

Answer (score 1):

This reminded me of this question: [Search html file for random string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8685245/725418), where I found (was shown) a good use for negative lookaround assertions, i.e. matching optional delimiters *and* avoiding partial matches.

Matching `-?123` is simple, the problems are

1. Not matching partial strings
2. Avoiding start/end of line mismatches
3. Avoid moving the `\G` anchor
4. Doing a lookbehind assertion of optional dash `-?`

I did not manage to solve #4, as variable length lookbehind assertions are not supported, so the fix is using a capture group.

Do note that some of the other answers to this question do not address these problems.

**Explanation:**

Negative lookbehind assertion for non-whitespace matches both whitespace and beginning of string, and assures we do not match partial strings. Then follows an optional dash in a capture group. The end of the match is a nested lookahead, where we must match `123` followed by anything that is not non-whitespace.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    s/(?<!\S)(-?)(?=123(?!\S))/$1./g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
r 123 z123 "123" -1233 d123 123-123
123 -123 -123 123 123
```

**Output:**

```
r .123 z123 "123" -1233 d123 123-123
.123 -.123 -.123 .123 .123
```

Comment: TLP, thanks for taking time to answer the question in great detail!

Comment: @GolamKawsar An interesting problem to solve is its own reward.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply this? This does not bother about the whitespaces, and works on perl 5.8.

```
echo '123 -123 -123  123' | perl -pe's/(-)?(123)/$1.$2/g'
```

Comment: It matches too much. It will also match `321123`.